# (htaccess) Pagination, if the npage parameter is equal to 1 redirect to relative base url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, pagination

I have 3 parameters in URL:

1. ?lang
2. &page
3. &npage

If the third parameter, npage, has the value 1, i need to redirect to relative base URL.

From URL

```
\en\news\npage-1\
```

I want to redirect to

```
\en\news\
```

My htaccess code is this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# first parameter (lang)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

# second parameter (page)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

# third parameter (npage) with pagination
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/npage-(\d+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&npage=$3 [L,QSA]

# if first page, redirect to relative base url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)npage=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What doesn't work? Give an example URL you are using in the browser, and what you expect to redirect to.

Comment: At example, I have the URL \en\news\npage-1\, and I want to redirect automatically to \en\news\  (hidding third parameter from URL) because then I have 2 duplicate pages: \en\news\ and \en\news\npage-1\ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.
Your code works if it is the last line in .htaccess, but if there are more lines after it, it doesn't work well.

In alternative, I'm trying this code and it works perfectly:

```
# third parameter (npage) with pagination 
# (if the parameter npage has value 0 or 1, redirect to relative base url)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/npage-([0-1]+)/$ $1/$2/ [R=301,L]

# third parameter (npage) with pagination
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/npage-(\d+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

And removing the old lines:

```
# if first page, redirect to relative base url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)npage=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# first parameter (lang)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

# second parameter (page)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

# third parameter (npage) with pagination
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/npage-(\d+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&npage=$3 [QSA]

# if first page, redirect to relative base url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)npage=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Without `[L]` flag